# What is the name of the service or group that writes the Django Log file on Apache with mod_wsgi?

Tags: django, apache, mod-wsgi, chown

I am having an issue with my Django Logger and after checking the Apache logs I can see that it is a permission error.

> [Mon Dec 15 22:15:22 2014] [error] [client 134.226.38.233] ValueError:
>   Unable to configure handler 'file': [Errno 13] Permission denied:
>   '/var/www/bias_experiment/src/survey.log', referer:
>   http://phaedrus.scss.tcd.ie/bias_experiment/surveyone/

I changed the owner and group of the file (from me) to www-data with `sudo chown www-data:www-data survey.log` but this had no effect. Setting the write permissions to 777 gets rid of the error but I understand this is bad practice.

[This answer to this question "Permission Denied when writing log file"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18547855/permission-denied-when-writing-log-file) has been very usefull but I do not understand one thing.

> "You must make sure that the owner of the file is the service that's
>   trying to write something to it or that the file belongs to group of
>   the service or you'll get a permission denied error."

What is the name of the service or group that writes the Django Log file?

**Setup:**

- Server: Ubuntu 12.04
- Apache 2.2.22
- mod_wsgi Version: 3.3-4ubuntu0.1
- Python 2.7.3
- Django 1.6

Answer (score 2, accepted):

is the same user that run apache. it depends by the OS, common values are

- www-data
- httpd

you must grant `write` and `execute` privileges to the directory that 'contains' the file.

Comment: When mod_wsgi is configured for embedded operation.

Comment: any way of checking which user runs Apache?

Comment: `ps axu | grep http` or `ls -al /var/www` or check your httpd.conf for lines 'User ' and 'Group '