# How to copy files to a folder which requires access permissions in python?

Tags: python, copy

I am trying to copy files to a location which requires access permissions(has **UserID** and **Password** to access the folder).

Is there a parameter or any special command to copy files to location which requires UserId and password?

Currently, I am using `shutil.copy2` to copy files but getting below error:

```
PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied:
```

Answer (score 1):

When you get that error, it could mean that you are trying to copy a file that is currently in use, like it's open, or your program opened but haven't closed it. Check to make sure it's closed.

If your file are `log` files, [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18547916/13552470) might help:

Comment: It is a network folder, it requires credentials to perform any operations. I have the credentials, I am not sure how to use the credentials and access folder in python.

Comment: what kind of files are you trying to copy?

Comment: I am trying to copy .log files